# How to auto increment a specific database table value for every store. (Laravel 6)

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database, laravel

How to Auto-Increment a specific database table value for every store.

I'm making a Queueing System and I have a DEPARTMENTS database table with 'name' 'letter' and 'number' as tables.

And I have a QUEUES database table with 'name' 'department' 'letter' 'number' as tables.
-the 'department =departments->name','letter = departments-> letter' and 'number =departments -> number' tables came from the DEPARTMENTS database's table values.

How to make the Queues->number to increase each time a queue is stored.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('queues.store') }}" autocomplete="off">
                                   @csrf

                                   <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">{{ __('Queue information') }}</h6>
                                   <div class="pl-lg-4">

                                       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('department') ? ' has-danger' : '' }} text-center">
                                           <div class="col">
                                           <label class="form-control-label text-lg" for="input-department">{{ __('Department') }}</label>
                                       </div>

                                               <div class="col text-center" data-toggle="buttons">
                                                   <div class="row text-center">
                                                       @foreach ($departments as $department)
                                                       <div class=" btn-group-toggle col-sm-12 col-md-4 text-center mt-2">
                                                           <label class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg w-100" onclick="getdept({{$department}})">
                                                               <input type="radio" name="department" value="{{ $department->name}}" sr-only required> {{ $department->name}}
                                                           </label>
                                                       </div>
                                                       @endforeach
                                                   </div>

                                           @if ($errors->has('department'))
                                               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('department') }}</strong>
                                               </span>
                                           @endif
                                       </div>
                                   </div>

                                       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                           <label class="form-control-label" for="input-name">{{ __('Name') }}</label>
                                           <input type="text" name="name" id="input-name" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Name') }}" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                           @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                               </span>
                                           @endif
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('snumber') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                           <label class="form-control-label" for="input-snumber">{{ __('Student number') }}</label>
                                           <input type="number" name="snumber" id="input-snumber" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('snumber') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Student number') }}" value="{{ old('snumber') }}" required autofocus>

                                           @if ($errors->has('snumber'))
                                               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('snumber') }}</strong>
                                               </span>
                                           @endif
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                           <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
                                           <input type="email" name="email" id="input-email" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Email') }}" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                           @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                               </span>
                                           @endif
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('transaction') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                           <label class="form-control-label" for="input-transaction">{{ __('Transaction') }}</label>
                                           <select class="form-control form-control-md" name="transaction" required>
                                               <option hidden value="">Choose Transaction...</option>
                                               <option >Transaction 1</option>
                                               <option >Transaction 2</option>
                                               <option>Transaction 3</option>

                                           </select>
                                           @if ($errors->has('transaction'))
                                               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('transaction') }}test</strong>
                                               </span>
                                           @endif
                                       </div>

                                       <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('remarks') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                                           <label class="form-control-label" for="input-name">{{ __('Notes / Remarks') }}</label>
                                           <textarea type="textarea" rows="5" name="remarks" id="input-name" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('remarks') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Notes / Remarks for the transaction...') }}" value="{{ old('remarks') }}" autofocus></textarea>

                                           @if ($errors->has('remarks'))
                                               <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                   <strong>{{ $errors->first('remarks') }}</strong>
                                               </span>
                                           @endif
                                       </div>

                                       <input type="hidden" name="letter" id="letter" value="">
                                       <input type="hidden" name="number" id="number" value="">

                                       <div class="text-center">
                                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </form>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>
           <div class="separator separator-bottom separator-skew zindex-100">
               <svg x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 2560 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                   <polygon class="fill-light" points="2560 0 2560 100 0 100"></polygon>
               </svg>
           </div>
       </div>

       <div class="container mt--10 pb-5"></div>

       <script>
           function getdept(dept) {
               document.getElementById('letter').value = dept.letter;
               document.getElementById('number').value = dept.number;
           }
       </script>
```

> This is my controller for Queue

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Department;
    use App\Queue;

    class QueueController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {

            $departments=Department::all();

            return view('queues.index',['departments' => $departments]);
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            $departments=Department::all();

            return view('queues.create',['departments' => $departments]);
        }



        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'snumber' => 'required|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|max:255',
                'department' => 'required|max:255',
                'transaction' => 'required|max:255',
                'letter' => 'required|max:255',
                'number' => 'required|max:255',
                'remarks' => 'nullable|max:255'
            ]);
            $queue = new Queue([
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'snumber' => $request->get('snumber'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'department' => $request->get('department'),
                'transaction' => $request->get('transaction'),
                'letter' => $request->get('letter'),
                'number' => $request->get('number'),
                'remarks' => $request->get('remarks'),
                'called' => 'no',

            ]);
            $queue->save();
            return redirect('/')->withStatus(__('Queue added successfully.'));
        }

        /**
         * Display the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function show($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function edit($id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Update the specified resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Remove the specified resource from storage.
         *
         * @param  int  $id
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function destroy($id)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'snumber' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|max:255',
            'department' => 'required|max:255',
            'transaction' => 'required|max:255',
            'letter' => 'required|max:255',
            'number' => 'required|max:255',
            'remarks' => 'nullable|max:255'
        ]);

        //get the last number in the database
        $number = Queue::orderBy('number', 'DESC')->first();

        $queue = new Queue([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'snumber' => $request->get('snumber'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'department' => $request->get('department'),
            'transaction' => $request->get('transaction'),
            'letter' => $request->get('letter'),
            'number' =>  $number + 1,
            'remarks' => $request->get('remarks'),
            'called' => 'no',

        ]);
        $queue->save();
        return redirect('/')->withStatus(__('Queue added successfully.'));
    }
```

Comment: I am getting this error 

ErrorException
Object of class App\Queue could not be converted to number